# Why does CombineMesh delete parts of my mesh?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on creating a building generator, and am trying to combine all walls of the building into a single mesh. The building itself is made of quite a lot of individual gameobjects, all parented under one gameobject. In play mode, the constructed building looks like this.

[image: Building in playmode]

I can export the gameobjects as a prefab just fine.

[image: Prefab]

The issue arises when I attempt to combine everything to a single mesh. It shows like this, with a great deal of vertices appearing to be missing. I've already considered that I could be running up against the vertice limit, but even after raising that limit, the issue remains unresolved. Recalculating the normals hasn't helped, either. Code below.

[image: Mesh]

```
MeshFilter[] filters = building.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
    Mesh finalMesh = new Mesh();
    finalMesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;
    Debug.Log("Filters " + filters.Length);
    CombineInstance[] combiners = new CombineInstance[filters.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < filters.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(filters[i].gameObject.name);
        combiners[i].subMeshIndex = 0;
        combiners[i].mesh = filters[i].sharedMesh;
        combiners[i].transform = filters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
    }

    finalMesh.CombineMeshes(combiners);
    finalMesh.RecalculateNormals();
    building.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
    building.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh = finalMesh;
    string localPath2 = buildingFolderPath + "/Building.asset";
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(finalMesh, localPath2);
    GameObject finalBuilding = PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(building, localPath);
```

I have no clue what could be happening. I've considered that it could be automatically removing intersecting polygons (unsure if that's even a factor with CombineMesh(), the documentation doesn't say anything about it) but even changing the gameobjects involved to very small sizes, to the point where intersection would be impossible, hasn't helped a bit.

A possible clue is that the mesh is only displaying T-junction walls, which are the largest of the walls. Could there be a connection between size and this issue?

As it stands, I've exhausted all of my possible ideas. What could be going on here? For reference, the models in question are simple blender models, more or less just planes, exported in fbx with read/write enabled.

EDIT: As suggested by shingo, I have counted the vertices in the building using the following code.

```
        MeshFilter[] filters = building.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
    Mesh finalMesh = new Mesh();
    finalMesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;
    CombineInstance[] combiners = new CombineInstance[filters.Length];
    long count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < filters.Length; i++)
    {
        combiners[i].subMeshIndex = 0;
        combiners[i].mesh = filters[i].sharedMesh;
        combiners[i].transform = filters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
        count += filters[i].sharedMesh.vertexCount;
    }

    Debug.Log("Final count is " + count);
```

In one experimental example, the final count given by the code was 39174 vertices, while the vertices recorded in the inspector of the corresponding mesh counted 28372. So there's a significant disparity, meaning that the vertices are actually being deleted, instead of just not displaying properly.

Comment: Does vertex and triangle count of the new mesh match the parts'?

Comment: @shingo Good idea, there is a significant disparity. I added an edit to the original post to show details

Comment: Notice `subMeshIndex` property, if your model contains submeshes, you should set it properly, otherwise only the first submesh will be combined into.